# How to get SPL token metadata using solscan api

Tags: reactjs, api, token, solana

I am trying to get token metadata using solscan api.
I have api key and used below code.

```
const data = await fetch(`https://pro-api.solscan.io/v1.0/nft/token/info/${tokenAddress}`, {
          "headers": {
            "accept": "application/json",
            "token": {apiKEY}
          }
        });
```

I followed this [step](https://docs.solscan.io/api-access/how-to-use-solscan-api) for using solscan api, but I got
[image: this response]

What's wrong with my code?

I can't use

```
METAPLEX.nfts().findByMint({mintAddress: new PublicKey(tokenAddress)})
```

since this token I am trying to get info has no metadata but solscan has it.
So I have to use solscan api.